# Redirect to another page using contact form 7?

Tags: customization, ajax, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using CF7 to send some information to my email and everything's working fine, but I need to redirect the users to a different page after the email has been sent, by default the forms are sent to the same page via ajax, I was thinking about setting a hidden field with the page url but since the form submits asynchronously I don't know how to set it in my page template. If the form was submitted normaly I'd do something like:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['hidden_field_url']) {
    wp_redirect($_REQUEST['hidden_field_url']);
}
```

So is there any way to send the form without ajax? Or maybe do what I need in any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, needed to add this to the additional settings option:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://www.url.com';"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your jQuery AJAX call you should add some javascript to redirect the page:

```
window.location.replace("http://wordpress.stackexchange.com");
```

Comment: Got it, I posted it as and answer below.